# Check in command line if a word is missing when a word exist in multiple files

Tags: arrays, shell, for-loop, grep

How can I have a list that tells me when a word (SecondWord in my example) is missing when another word (FirstWord in ma example) has been write.

File1.txt:

> Hello FirstWord ... SecondWord
>
> ...
>
> ... FirstWord ...
>
> FirstWord ... SecondWord
>
> FirstWord ... ...
>
> Hello ... SecondWord

File2.txt:

> Hello FirstWord ... SecondWord
>
> FirstWord ...

I would like a file at the end with line and filename :

> 3 : File1
>
> 5 : File1
>
> 2 : File2

I think what I try to do is overkill :/

```
   filename='test.txt'
lineArray[0]=0
filesAwaitable[0]=$lineArray
grep -r -n 'FirstWord ' Sources/ --include=\*.txt | awk -F: '{print $2":"$1}' > $filename
while read line; 
    do 
        IFS=:
        ary=($line)
        for key in "${!ary[@]}";
            do
                if [[ $filesAwaitable["$key"] != *"${ary[$key]}"* ]]; then
                    filesAwaitable["$key"] = "${ary[$key]}"
                    echo "${ary[$key]}";
                fi
                
                #grep -n -r 'SecondWord' line | awk -F: '{print $2":"$1}'
                
            done
    done < $filename
```

Thx for your help

Comment: Which line in your example `File1.txt` is line 5? Which word is the _missing_ word, and which word is _another word_?

Comment: Hello, I edit my question to better indent. In my example I want to know when SecondWord is missing when FirstWord has been written before.

Comment: Thx, you are right. Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case a Perl solution is okay, here is a straightforward one with the same regular expression as for GNU grep:

```
perl -ne 'print "$. : $ARGV\n" if /FirstWord((?!SecondWord).)*$/; close ARGV if eof' File?.txt
```

> How can I use this command in all Source/ folder for all .txt files?

You can use `find` for this:

```
find Source -name \*.txt|xargs perl …
```

(without the `File?.txt` at the end of the `perl`command).

Comment: This seems perfect, thx. I had to replace by -nle coz grep -P does not work anymore. How can I use this command in all Source/ folder for all .txt files?

Comment: @B.Brigitte - Replacing the `File?.txt` with `subfolder/*.txt` should be sufficient _to make it look in all txt files in subfolder_.

Comment: what about subfolder on subfolder that i don't know?

Comment: subfolder/*.txt if there is no txt file in this subfolder. it create an error

Comment: @B.Brigitte - I expanded the answer.

Comment: thx a lot. Could not have done without you. Thx for your patient

Comment: It possible with find to exclude specific files?

Comment: @B.Brigitte - To exclude e. g. the file `test.txt`, we can do with: `find Source -name \*.txt ! -name test.txt …`.

Answer (score 0):

> In my example I want to know when SecondWord is missing when FirstWord has been written before.

If you have a `grep` which understands perl regular expressions, you can directly specify a pattern for *FirstWord not followed by SecondWord anywhere until the end of line*:

```
grep -nP 'FirstWord((?!SecondWord).)*$' File?.txt
```

This yields for the given examples:

```
File1.txt:3:... FirstWord ...
File1.txt:5:FirstWord ... ...
File2.txt:2:FirstWord ...
```

To rearrange that to the desired output format, you can pipe it through

```
awk -F: '{print $2,":",$1}'
```

Comment: Thx Armali, what is -P ? seems perfect to do it in one line. But It does not work

Comment: @B.Brigitte - _`-P`, `--perl-regexp`˿
              Interpret  PATTERN as a Perl regular expression._ This option is available in GNU grep; perhaps you can install that, or I'll think about an approach without it (but that would be much more complicated, similar to yours - or would you be okay with using `perl`?).

Answer (score 0):

If the shell is `bash`, the problem can be solved easily with the [extended pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) operator `!(pattern)`, which matches anything except the given *pattern*:

```
shopt -s extglob    # enable extended pattern matching features
for file in "$@"
do  lineno=0
    while read line
    do  ((++lineno))
        case "$line" in *FirstWord!(*SecondWord))   echo $lineno : $file
        esac
    done <$file
done
```